# Moving data between accounts on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, permissions

I recently upgraded to Mac OS 10.15 (Catalina), from a much older version (El Capitan) that I'd been using for years. After the upgrade I had a lot of weird problems with apps hanging, but I've found (fingers crossed) that those problems don't occur if I use a different user account.

I realise I could mess around in `~/Preferences` and so on to find the problem, but it seems easier and safer to just transfer all my relevant data from the old account and only use the new account from now on.

However, these new versions of Mac OS are apparently very fussy about file permissions, so I want to make sure I do that in the right way. Is it enough just to do, for example,

```
 % sudo mv /Users/old_account/Documents /Users/new_account/
 % sudo chown -R new_account /Users/new_account/Documents
```

Or should I do something else to make sure the permissions will be correct for a new version of Mac OS?

I realise it's kind of a basic question, but I really don't want to end up with the same weird problems coming back again due to getting these (to me) arcane things wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest might be to just change ACLs on their old User directory entirely.

Navigate to their home folder at `/Users/[their name]` & Get Info on it  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd> 
Unlock the padlock at the bottom right
Click the  <kbd>+</kbd>  at bottom left & add your 'new' user
Set Privilege to 'Read & Write'
Click the Gear icon  <kbd>⚙︎⌵</kbd>   & select 'Apply to enclosed items'
Done.

You now have unlimited access to that folder & all its contents.

This is one I did earlier - tetsujin is the user I'm taking control of…

[image]